# V-REP's Lua `tonumber` returns nil on Linux

Tags: lua, type-conversion, multiplatform

We developed a simple [V-REP](http://www.coppeliarobotics.com/) simulation that works pretty well on OS X but not on Linux (Ubuntu 15.04). [Lua](http://www.lua.org/) is employed as the main scripting language.

We attach the following code (with the return values in comments) that unfortunately returns `nil` on Linux (but converts `e[3]` to number without problem on OS X):

```
e[3]                   -- -0.677782532263
type(e[3])             -- string
type(tonumber(e[3]))   -- nil
```

What is really interesting is the fact that the previous code works as one would expect in Lua 5.2.3 console (both OS X and Linux). However, V-REP can't convert the string to number properly when running on Linux.

We tried both [32b and 64b V-REP versions](http://www.coppeliarobotics.com/downloads.html) (today downloaded) with exactly same results - `nil`s. Could you please point out some things we're missing? Neither Lua nor V-REP are utils we use every day.

**Edit 1:**
I Use Ubuntu 15.04. V-REP uses Lua 5.1, My Lua version:

```
$ apt-cache policy lua5.1
lua5.1:
  Installed: 5.1.5-7.1
  Candidate: 5.1.5-7.1
  Version table:
 *** 5.1.5-7.1 0
        500 http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

In console, I tried the following:

```
$ lua
Lua 5.1.5  Copyright (C) 1994-2012 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> e={[3]="-0.677782532263"}; print(e[3], type(e[3]), tonumber(e[3]), type(tonumber(e[3])))
-0.677782532263 string  -0.677782532263 number
```

Packages

Comment: Do you really get `Nil` printed out? Or is it `nil`? You are sure that you are using the same version of lua on both OS X and linux when this happens? And both of the first two lines output the same value on OS X and linux when this happens?

Comment: Hello Etan, we get `nil`, the version is the same on both platforms, and about the output - the values are dynamically created in python and sent via remote api to vrep (and lua), so they are not the same exact values, but the error doesn't happen on os x at all and happens on linux on all the float numbers that get passed in.

Comment: @EtanReisner it's exactly as Gyfis wrote.

Comment: What do you get for the value of `e[3]` if you try `print(("%q"):format(e[3]))`? What distribution of linux is this? What lua package exactly? Can you get that value to work in lua itself (without vrep) if you try it manually? (i.e. `e={[3]="-0.677782532263"}; print(e[3], type(e[3]), tonumber(e[3]))`?)

Comment: @EtanReisner please see my edit 1 with answers. It seems like it works in console.

Comment: `lua5.1-policy-dev` is not a lua package. It is the debian policy for lua packages. Also for the wrong version of lua (since you are using 5.2.3). Assuming that's the version of lua being used it can clearly handle the number itself correctly. Which means either some other version of lua is in use which can't or the string isn't exactly what you think it is sometimes. Where does the value of `e[3]` come from in the first place? Can you print it out using the `%q` formatter to make sure it doesn't have anything "odd" in it?

Comment: @EtanReisner Oh I'm sorry about the wrong package. I corrected the edit. We print the string and `%q` formatter in V-REP with the following result `0.610542045088` and `"0.610542045088"`

Comment: @EtanReisner we found out what lua version V-REP uses (5.1) so I installed it on my pc as well. I also updated the question in order to match the current situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is caused by the fact that *V-REP* uses *Lua 5.1*, and the computers we tested it on had different locales for numbers (the linux had `LC_NUMERIC=cs_CZ.UTF-8` and the mac had, probably, `en_US`).

That means that Lua on Mac recognized the float numbers in strings as numbers, but Lua on Linux with the different locale did not - it didn't have a *comma* (e.g. `-3,513`) as a decimal separator that the locale required, so it returned nil for the conversion.

The fix is to set the `LC_NUMERIC` flag before running the vrep to the `en_US` locale, like this:

```
...$ LC_NUMERIC=en_US.UTF-8 ./vrep
```

which would force the locale to be a dot-based, and enable Lua to recognize the numbers.

Thanks @Etan for all the help and for poking at the issue from the right direction.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you for great solution!

Answer (score 0):

Another way to set locale from lua code like this os.setlocale("C")

Not all systems can change the locale of an arbitrary application at startup, sometimes it will be necessary to change the locale of the entire system, which can be inconvenient for other applications. If the script distributed with V-REP is distributed in the same way with XML files in which the separator is a period, rather than a comma, then it is logical that before the tonumber function is called, the correct console should be installed from LUA and not outside, through the variables of the open environment.

The LUA documentation clearly describes what the os.setLocale function is used for, and it clearly states that it affects the conversion of strings to number. And there it is indicated in the need to make sure the correct settings before calling the conversion functions.

In addition, the script that changes the locale within itself is more portable, because does not require the person who launched the knowledge of what environment variables for V-REP should be specified from the outside.

Comment: Well, the accepted answer does set the locale as the solution, as far as I understand. So it's not completely off. Still, as it stands, this answer is not very useful. I would suggest substantial editing or conversion to a comment.